# Spring-boot on Ubuntu 64bit - cannot start

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, ubuntu

I have a problem with `spring-boot:run` on Ubuntu 15.10 64bit. On Windows 7 64bit everything works fine - application starts, also on Ubuntu 32bit.

On 64bit I can compile source code, but server is not starting (but I can compile sources with `mvn install` and deploy on Tomcat). Console log

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.Application.main(Application.java:62) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:450) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a228cee9.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$35(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a228cee9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5d1b9162.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a228cee9.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46.569s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 06 12:40:32 CET 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 46M/442M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I'm deploying *.war file on Tomcat everything works fine. I was searching everywhere - nothing works. Will be very pleased for any help!

Fragment of pom.xml file (configuration):

```
   <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu</groupId>
    <artifactId>wdialogu</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>wdialogu</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <HikariCP.version>2.3.5</HikariCP.version>
        <assertj-core.version>2.0.0</assertj-core.version>
        <awaitility.version>1.4.0</awaitility.version>
        <codahale-metrics.version>3.0.2</codahale-metrics.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail.version>1.8.4</geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail.version>
        <google-maps-services.version>0.1.6</google-maps-services.version>
        <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
        <!--<jackson.version>2.4.6</jackson.version>-->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
        <jhipster-loaded.version>0.12</jhipster-loaded.version>
        <joda-time-hibernate.version>1.3</joda-time-hibernate.version>
        <json-path.version>0.9.1</json-path.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate.version>3.3</liquibase-hibernate.version>
        <liquibase-slf4j.version>1.2.1</liquibase-slf4j.version>
        <liquibase.version>3.1.1</liquibase.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.3.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-sortpom-plugin.version>2.3.0</maven-sortpom-plugin.version>
        <metrics-spring.version>3.0.2</metrics-spring.version>
        <postgis.version>2.1.5</postgis.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</postgresql.version>

        <reflections.version>0.9.9-RC1</reflections.version>
        <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>2.2</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <!--<spring-boot-starter.version>1.2.5.RELEASE</spring-boot-starter.version>-->
        <!--<spring-boot.version>1.2.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>-->

        <!--<spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>-->
        <swagger-springmvc.version>0.8.8</swagger-springmvc.version>
        <tt4j.version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</tt4j.version>
        <usertype-core.version>3.2.0.GA</usertype-core.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: turn on DEBUG logging in logback.xml file ( or log4j.properties ) so you get more info whats wrong. Also check maven versions on all operation systems, probably there is some difference.

Comment: DEBUG is on in logback.xml, and I paste the log. Maven version is the same as declare in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see, you are getting error while building the project using maven.
Looks like, you have integration test cases it runs while running build. One possible solution could be avoid running integration test cases while building project.
This link should help you [Spring boot with scheduler-BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Singleton bean creation not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434677/spring-boot-with-scheduler-beancreationnotallowedexception-error-creating-bean)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work for me (both solutions) - got the same error.

Comment: Could you share the complete console log?

Comment: I've shared log in 2 posts.

Answer (score 0):

Complete console log part 1(more than 30000 chars so I put it in two parts):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7535 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/uziak/Programy/idea-IU-143.1184.17/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar:/home/uziak/Programy/idea-IU-143.1184.17/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=15.0.2 spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building wdialogu 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ wdialogu >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ wdialogu ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ wdialogu ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 22 resources
[INFO] Copying 76 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy (copy) @ wdialogu ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: io.github.jhipster.loaded:agent:0.12:jar
[INFO] Copying agent-0.12.jar to /home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental/spring_loaded/springloaded-jhipster.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ wdialogu ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 531 source files to /home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental/target/classes
[WARNING] /home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental/src/main/java/pl/edu/pw/ii/wdialogu/ApplicationWebXml.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental/src/main/java/pl/edu/pw/ii/wdialogu/ApplicationWebXml.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[WARNING] /home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental/src/main/java/pl/edu/pw/ii/wdialogu/service/util/CollectionDozerBeanMapper.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental/src/main/java/pl/edu/pw/ii/wdialogu/service/util/CollectionDozerBeanMapper.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ wdialogu ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ wdialogu ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ wdialogu <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) @ wdialogu ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
[DEBUG] org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
[INFO] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.Application - Starting Application on uziak-ThinkPad-L440 with PID 7874 (/home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental/target/classes started by uziak in /home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental)
[DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.Application - Running with Spring Boot v1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, Spring v4.2.3.RELEASE
[INFO] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.Application - The following profiles are active: dev
[WARN] org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
[WARN] org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
[DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.AsyncConfiguration - Creating Async Task Executor
[DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Java version: 1.8.0_66
[DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Datasource
[DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.citizendata.CitizenDatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Citizen Datasource
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.ForumPostAttachment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.Address]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.messages.Message]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.FormField]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.EhcacheAccessStrategyFactoryImpl - HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.FormField]
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.BinaryData]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.SelectionOperand]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.Department]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.AnnotationRange]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.DebateMembership]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.DebateRealization]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.ExpertAnswer]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.report.ReportVersion]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.Survey]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.report.Report]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.contactForm.ContactForm]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.SelectionOperator]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.EhcacheAccessStrategyFactoryImpl - HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.SelectionOperator]
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.Expert]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.SelectionAttributeValue]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.Annotation]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.dictionary.DictionaryItem]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.SelectionAttribute]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.notification.Task]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.ExpertConsultation]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.messages.Inbox]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.ReportedForumPost]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.Affiliation]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.DebateProposedSolutionPositionPreference]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.TeamTalkActiveLink]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.notification.Notification]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.OperandDefinition]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.EhcacheAccessStrategyFactoryImpl - HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.OperandDefinition]
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.comment.DebateArgumentComment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.QuestionForExpert]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.QuestionForExpertPositionPreference]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.SelectionCriterion]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.UserGuideEntry]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.comment.QuestionForDebateComment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.InfoMaterialType]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.EhcacheAccessStrategyFactoryImpl - HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.InfoMaterialType]
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.QuestionForDebate]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.messages.Thread]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.comment.DebateProposedSolutionComment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.ConsultationComment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.FormSection]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.EhcacheAccessStrategyFactoryImpl - HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.FormSection]
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.DebateArgument]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.messages.InboxThread]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.File]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.Attachment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.comment.QuestionForExpertComment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.Debate]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.ReportConsultationComment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.contactForm.ProblemReport]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.DebateProposedSolution]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.comment.ExpertAnswerComment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.DebateType]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.EhcacheAccessStrategyFactoryImpl - HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.DebateType]
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.Question]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.InfoMaterialVersionPreConsultation]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.SurveyResponse]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.InfoMaterialVersion]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.SelectionAttributeType]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.EhcacheAccessStrategyFactoryImpl - HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.selection.SelectionAttributeType]
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.InfoMaterialConsultationComment]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.debate.DebateMembershipGroup]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.domain.dictionary.DictionaryType]; using defaults.
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
[WARN] org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete console log part 2:

```
    [DEBUG] org.reflections.Reflections - going to scan these urls:
    file:/home/uziak/Projekty/wdialogu-experimental/target/classes/
    [INFO] org.reflections.Reflections - Reflections took 23 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 7 keys and 15 values 
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.MetricsConfiguration - Registering JVM gauges
    [INFO] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.MetricsConfiguration - Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
    [INFO] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.WebConfigurer - Web application configuration, using profiles: [dev]
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.WebConfigurer - Initializing Metrics registries
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.WebConfigurer - Registering Metrics Filter
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.WebConfigurer - Registering Metrics Servlet
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.WebConfigurer - Registering static resources development Filter
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.WebConfigurer - Registering GZip Filter
    [INFO] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.WebConfigurer - Web application fully configured
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.MailConfiguration - Configuring mail server
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.MailConfiguration - smtp.gmail.com 587 wdialogu2 123haslo smtp
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.CacheConfiguration - Starting Ehcache
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.CacheConfiguration - Registering Ehcache Metrics gauges
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Liquibase
    [INFO] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.Application - Running with Spring profile(s) : [dev]
    [WARN] org.dozer.config.GlobalSettings - Dozer configuration file not found: dozer.properties.  Using defaults for all Dozer global properties.
    [INFO] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.ThymeleafConfiguration - loading non-reloadable mail messages resources
    [DEBUG] org.reflections.Reflections - going to scan these urls:
    jar:file:/home/uziak/.m2/repository/TT4J-wdialogu/core/1.1-SNAPSHOT/core-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/
    [INFO] org.reflections.Reflections - Reflections took 4 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 1 keys and 13 values 
    [WARN] org.springframework.batch.core.listener.AbstractListenerFactoryBean - org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader is an interface.  The implementing class will not be queried for annotation based listener configurations.  If using @StepScope on a @Bean method, be sure to return the implementing class so listner annotations can be used.
    [WARN] org.springframework.batch.core.listener.AbstractListenerFactoryBean - org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader is an interface.  The implementing class will not be queried for annotation based listener configurations.  If using @StepScope on a @Bean method, be sure to return the implementing class so listner annotations can be used.
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.auditEventRepository() with argument[s] = []
    [DEBUG] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exit: pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.auditEventRepository() with result = pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository$1@7279d0f8
    [WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    [INFO] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.CacheConfiguration - Remove Cache Manager metrics
    [INFO] pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.config.CacheConfiguration - Closing Cache Manager
    [ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at pl.edu.pw.ii.wdialogu.Application.main(Application.java:63) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:450) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f83e8c7.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$42(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f83e8c7$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7b60684a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f83e8c7.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 34.486 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-06T23:22:24+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 49M/472M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`mvn spring-boot:run` should work.